Adding proxy to selenium and undetected chromedriver
I am using Selenium and Python to scrape multiple pages. I do want to use concurrency, but my proxies are giving "error no proxy address." Is it because I am using Selenium and an undetected web driver? What should I change?
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, TimeoutError
import time
import random
import undetected_chromedriver as UC

# Define WebDriver path and proxy settings (masked for privacy)
webdriver_path = "\\path\\to\\chromedriver.exe"
proxies = [
    "http://username:password@proxy1.example.com:port",
    "http://username:password@proxy2.example.com:port"
]

def setup_driver(proxy=None):
    options = UC.ChromeOptions()
    options.headless = False
    options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
    options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
    options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
    options.add_argument(f"user-agent={random.choice(user_agents)}")
    if proxy:
        options.add_argument(f'--proxy-server={proxy}')
    driver = UC.Chrome(service=UC.Service(webdriver_path), options=options)
    driver.execute_script("Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'webdriver', {get: () => undefined})")
    return driver

def main(unique_urls, output_file):
    existing_urls = load_existing_urls(output_file)
    print(f"Loaded {len(existing_urls)} existing URLs")

    drivers = [setup_driver(proxies[0]), setup_driver(proxies[1]), setup_driver()]

    results = []
    flag = 1

    try:
        # Initial setup with local connection
        if flag == 1:
            data = scrape_urls(drivers[2], unique_urls[0], flag=1)
            if data:
                results.append(data)
            flag = 0  # Reset flag after initial setup
        
        with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=3) as executor:
            futures = []
            for i, base_url in enumerate(unique_urls):
                if url_exists_in_existing(existing_urls, base_url):
                    continue

                driver = drivers[i % 3]  # Rotate drivers for each URL
                future = executor.submit(scrape_urls, driver, base_url, flag=0)
                futures.append(future)

            for future in futures:
                try:
                    data = future.result(timeout=5)
                    if data:
                        results.append(data)
                except TimeoutError:
                    print(f"Timeout for URL: {base_url}, retrying...")
                    driver.refresh()
                except Exception as e:
                    print(f"Unexpected error: {e}")

                # Write results in batches of 10
                if len(results) >= 10:
                    append_row_to_csv(output_file, results)
                    results.clear()

            if results:
                append_row_to_csv(output_file, results)
                print("Final batch written to CSV.")

    finally:
        for driver in drivers:
            driver.quit()

output_file = "products.csv"
main(unique_urls, output_file)

I have spent hours on this any help will be useful. Unnecessary functions have been excluded for brevity.
